# Большие проекты

Tags: компиляция, c++

Здравствуйте! У меня возник такой вопрос. Есть различные проекты в которых имеется огромный объем кода. Ну скажем какой-нибудь Google Chrome. Как такие проекты можно разрабатывать с помощью IDE? Наверняка любая среда просто заглохнет от такого огромного количества файлов с кодом и такого объема кода. К тому же наверняка такие проекты очень очень долго компилируются. Как эти проблемы решают взрослые и умные дяденьки?

Comment: Взрослые и умные дяденьки разбивают такие проекты на обособленные модули и используют инкрементальную компиляцию.

Comment: а для полной сборки используют make, cmake и даже самописные утилиты.

Но есть одна ide (а даже две), которые не заглохнут от такого кол-ва кода. Это vim и emacs.

Но в любом случае всегда работает принцип "разделяй и властвуй".

Comment: @KoVadim vim-то каким боком в IDE попал? linux с vim -- согласен, голый vim -- редактор.

Comment: а Вы много знаете IDE, которые умеют работать без ОС? я знаю только один такой редактор - печатная машинка.


А по поводу эмакса вопросов нет?

Comment: @KoVadim: В современных печатных машинках бежит небось какой-нибудь embedded linux :)

А по [поводу Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war#Humor):

> Emacs is a great operating system, but it lacks a decent editor

Comment: с эмаксом почти нет проблем - уже почти готово https://gitorious.org/evil

Comment: @KoVadim чего же змеюку-то забыли? http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode Ей уже много годков. Да и эмуляторов других редакторов хватает, brif/crisp, EDT, ...

Comment: Видимо Вы пользуетесь вимом только раз в пару лет. Viper - это vi эмулятор. У них даже на сайте написано

> If you want Vim features too, use Evil instead.

Comment: @KoVadim не совсем так. Я viper запускал несколько раз в жизни. И очень давно.

Comment: А что, в emacs действительно многие пользуют vi-mode? 

Не представляю -- зачем?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDE, в принципе, вывозят это нормально.

К примеру, с LLVM/Clang на моей машине (MacBook Pro, Late 2011) работать можно, Xcode/AppCode прекрасно с ними справляются, индексация длится довольно долго, но зато потом можно работать нормально.

Касательно компиляции - все зависит от организации кода, есть как минимум два варианта решения этой проблемы, которые прекрасно сочетаются:

1. Разбиение всей программы на модули. Это позволит собрать каждый модуль единожды (либо получить этот модуль уже в собранном виде) и пересобирать потом только тот модуль, с которым вы работаете. По сути так работают все системы: вам не приходится всякий раз пересобирать ядро, чтобы скомпилировать "Hello world", вы просто подключаете ([компонуете](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150327/)) сторонние библиотеки (static libs, dynamic libs).
2. Инкрементальная сборка. Вы имеет при себе все исходники и собираете их все только один раз, затем пересобирается только тот код, который вы правили (и его зависимости). Для уменьшения количества зависимостей стоит помнить о предварительном объявлении ([Forward Declaration](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). [Здесь](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/08/09/using-forward-declaration-in-your-objective-c-projects/) можно почитать о том как этим пользоваться в Objective-C, понимаю что это не совсем ваш профиль, но в статье есть наглядный (имхо) пример, который поможет понять почему это действительно важно.

**P.S.** я не являюсь достаточно опытным экспертом в данной области, потому будьте бдительны и воспринимайте мой ответ скорее как "размышления на тему".

Comment: @AlexDenisov соглашусь. Я в IDE (а именно - соответствующей версии MSVC) открывал достаточно большие проекты - вроде графических движков игр Q3, HL2 и ниче - никто не умер :-) Правда, тормозило по началу и в определенные моменты работы, но, в целом, нормально.